# Is there a quick way to convert all values in a column to True/False values?

Tags: sql-server

For example I have the following table

```
+--------+-----------------------+--+
|   Id   |    BuyingAttribute    |  |
+--------+-----------------------+--+
| 1      |    Low Price          |  |
| 1      |    Good Communication |  |
| 1      |    English Speaker    |  |
| 2      |    Low Price          |  |
| ...etc | ...etc                |  |
+--------+-----------------------+--+
```

Is there a way that I could transfer all the values automatically to yes/No values. I know that I can use case statement  like so

```
SELECT
    Id,
    CASE WHEN BuyingAttribute = 'Low Price' THEN True ELSE False END AS Buying Attribute
FROM
    myTable
```

However, is there an automated  method, because it will be time consuming if I have 50 values and write 50 case statement to generate results like below

```
+----+-----------------------+---------------+-------------------------+----------------------+
| Id |  BuyingAttribute      | BA(Low Price) |  BA(Good Communication) |  BA(English Speaker) |  
+----+-----------------------+---------------+-------------------------+----------------------+
|  1 |    Low Price          |   True        |   False                 |   False              |  
|  1 |    Good Communication |   False       |   True                  |   False              |  
|  1 |    English Speaker    |   False       |   False                 |   True               |  
|  2 |    Low Price          |   True        |   False                 |   False              |  
|    |                       |               |                         |                      |  
+----+-----------------------+---------------+-------------------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: and how we decide which value will true and which will false

Comment: Don't you just need 1 row for each id dropping the buying attribute column in your result set.

Comment: Is there a table which defines all the possible attributes?

Comment: By time consuming I take you mean time consuming to write?

Comment: Have a look at PIVOT (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Write a function that takes the table, field name and value to compare, then return true or false, its then easy to include in your query with fn(table, field, 'value');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by allocating all possible buying attributes to all ids like this

```
select tid,row_number() over (partition by tid order by baba) rn,
        baba,
        t.BuyingAttribute tba
from
(
select distinct t.id tid, ba.buyingattribute baba from t
cross join (select distinct t.BuyingAttribute from t) ba
) s
left join t on t.BuyingAttribute = s.baba and t.id = s.tid
```

Result

```
tid         rn                   baba                           tba
----------- -------------------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------
1           1                    English Speaker                English Speaker
1           2                    Good Communication             Good Communication
1           3                    Low Price                      Low Price
2           1                    English Speaker                NULL
2           2                    Good Communication             NULL
2           3                    Low Price                      Low Price
```

We can then wrap this in a pivot

```
select tid,rn,
    case when [English Speaker] is not null then 'true' else 'false' end as 'English Speaker',
    case when [Good Communication] is not null then 'true' else 'false' end as 'Good Communication',
    case when [Low Price] is not null then 'true' else 'false' end as 'Low Price'
from
(
select tid,row_number() over (partition by tid order by baba) rn,
        baba,
        t.BuyingAttribute tba
from
(
select distinct t.id tid, ba.buyingattribute baba from t
cross join (select distinct t.BuyingAttribute from t) ba
) s
left join t on t.BuyingAttribute = s.baba and t.id = s.tid
--order by tid, baba
) t
pivot (max(baba) for baba in ([English Speaker],[Good Communication],[Low Price])) pvt 
order by tid,rn
```

to get

```
tid         rn                   English Speaker Good Communication Low Price
----------- -------------------- --------------- ------------------ ---------
1           1                    true            false              false
1           2                    false           true               false
1           3                    false           false              true
2           1                    true            false              false
2           2                    false           true               false
2           3                    false           false              true
```

This would be a problem for you because you don't know how many buyingattributes you have so we need to build the above statement and execute dynamic sql.

```
declare @s1 nvarchar(max)
declare @s10 varchar(max)
declare @s9 varchar(max)

set @s1 = 'select tid,rn,'

set @s9 = (
          select top 1  STUFF((
          SELECT 'case when [' + t1.buyingattribute + '] is not null then ' + char(39) +  'true' + char(39) + 
          ' else ' + char(39) + 'false' + char(39) + ' end as ' + char(39) + t1.buyingattribute + char(39) + ','  
          from t t1 where t1.buyingattribute >= t.buyingattribute
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'nVARCHAR(max)'), 1, 1, '')
          from 
          (select distinct buyingattribute from t) t
        )
--select substring(@s9,patindex('%,%',@s9)+ 1, len(@s9) - patindex('%,%',@s9))
--select @s9
set @s9 = substring(@s9,1,len(@s9) -1)
set @s1 = concat(@s1,substring(@s9,patindex('%,%',@s9)+ 1, len(@s9) - patindex('%,%',@s9)))


set @s10 = ' from
(
select tid,row_number() over (partition by tid order by baba) rn,
        baba,
        t.BuyingAttribute tba
from
(
select distinct t.id tid, ba.buyingattribute baba from t
cross join (select distinct t.BuyingAttribute from t) ba
) s
left join t on t.BuyingAttribute = s.baba and t.id = s.tid
--order by tid, baba
) t
pivot (max(baba) for baba in ('

set @s9 = (
          select top 1  STUFF((
          SELECT '[' + t1.buyingattribute + '] ,'  
          from t t1 where t1.buyingattribute >= t.buyingattribute
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'nVARCHAR(max)'), 1, 1, '')
          from 
          (select distinct buyingattribute from t) t
        )
set @s9 = substring(@s9,1,len(@s9) - 1)
set @s1 = concat(@s1,@s10,substring(@s9,patindex('%,%',@s9)+ 1, len(@s9) - patindex('%,%',@s9)),' )) pvt order by tid,rn')



exec sp_executesql @s1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Create table #tmp (Id int, BuyingAttribute VARCHAR(30))

    insert into #tmp values(1,'Low Price')
    insert into #tmp values(1,'Good Communication')
    insert into #tmp values(1,'English Speaker')
    insert into #tmp values(2,'Low Price')


    SELECT * FROM #tmp

    SELECT * ,
        CASE  BuyingAttribute WHEN 'Low Price' THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END [BA(Low Price)],
        CASE  BuyingAttribute WHEN 'Good Communication' THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END [BA(Good Communication)],
        CASE  BuyingAttribute WHEN 'English Speaker' THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END [BA(English Speaker)]

    FROM #tmp
    Drop table #tmp
```

Comment: That's almost exactly what OP does not want to do.